# Transfer files from one S3 bucket to another S3 bucket using python boto3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I want to transfer files from one s3 bucket path (say `B1/x/*`) to another S3 bucket (say `B2/y/*`), where B1 and B2 are two s3 buckets and x and y are folders in them which contain csv files respectively.

I have written below script to do this. But I am getting error `object_list' is not defined. Moreover, I am not sure whether it will perform the job of transferring files or not.

Refer the script below:

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.client("s3")
# list_objects_v2() give more info

more_objects=True
found_token = True
while more_objects :
  if found_token :
    response= s3.list_objects_v2(
      Bucket="B1", 
      Prefix="x/",
      Delimiter="/")
  else:   
    response= s3.list_objects_v2(
      Bucket="B1",
      ContinuationToken=found_token,
      Prefix="x/",
      Delimiter="/")
  # use copy_object or copy_from
  for source in object_list["Contents"]:
    raw_name = source["Key"].split("/")[-1] 
    new_name = "new_structure/{}".format(raw_name)
    s3.copy_from(CopySource='B1/x')      
    # Now check there is more objects to list
    if "NextContinuationToken" in response:
      found_token = response["NextContinuationToken"]
      more_objects = True
    else:
      more_objects = False
```

It would be really helpful if anyone could help me in making changes in the above script.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code to transfer files from one bucket to another in a     layered folder structure like yours. Here you won't have to define any     specific key or folder structure, the code takes care of that:

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
src_bucket = s3.Bucket('bucket_name')
dest_bucket = s3.Bucket('bucket_name')
dest_bucket.objects.all().delete()  #this is optional clean bucket
for obj in src_bucket.objects.all():
    s3.Object('dest_bucket', obj.key).put(Body=obj.get()["Body"].read())
```

If you want to clear your source bucket once the files are moved, you can 
use `src_bucket.objects.all().delete()` at the end of your code to clean the 
source bucket.

Answer (score 0):

If your script running in local server and want to access two buckets for transferring files from one s3 bucket to another, you can follow below code .This create a copy of files in "bucket1" to "sample" folder in  "bucket2".

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
src_bucket = s3.Bucket('bucket1')
dest_bucket = s3.Bucket('bucket2')
for obj in src_bucket.objects.all():
    filename= obj.key.split('/')[-1]
    dest_bucket.put_object(Key='sample/' + filename, Body=obj.get()["Body"].read())
```

I you want to remove files after copying from source bucket,below code can use within the loop after copying.

```
s3.Object(src_bucket, obj.key).delete()
```